# 'Keypress" event called twice when using arrow function notation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

I expect each key pressed to be logged once each time that key is pressed, however each key is logged twice each time it is pressed. But, only when using arrow notation for the function handed to the Event Listener.

```
class Test extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    window.addEventListener('keypress', (e) => this.KeyPress(e)) //works fine with this.KeyPress
  }
  
  KeyPress(e){
  console.log(e.key)
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>hi there</h1>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Confusingly this code works as expected on jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/wgqs75pr/4/
But, it does not work as expected on a brand new create-react-app.

Why is this.KeyPress called twice for every KeyPress?

Comment: Is there any reason why you choose to use class components instead of hooks?

Comment: @ChristianMoen This is extracted from a much larger class that is more suited to being a class component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that each key is key is logged twice is because there are two event handlers for `keypress`. This is most likely because react is running in [strict mode](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html) and so the constructor is called twice. This is also the reason why the code works fine on jsfiddle, as strict mode is disabled in production mode.

To fix this instead attach the event handler in the `componentDidMount` lifecycle function:

```
class Test extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }
  
  KeyPress(e){
    console.log(e.key)
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('keypress', (e) => this.keyPress(e))
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>hi there</h1>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

It may also be useful to remove the event listener in `componentWillUnmount` otherwise you may get unintended behaviour.

Comment: Wouldn't you use `window.addEventListener('keypress', this.keyPress.bind(this))`?

Comment: @samthecodingman Probably but I have just finished the react tutorial and they use the arrow notation to circumvent the binding of `this`.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it does not make sense to still using class components, they are not suited for bigger components.

If it is because you follow the old guidance of having *stateless* and *state* components, this pattern has been deprecated when React hooks was announced. And I suggest that you look into how hooks will solve a lot of annoying bugs like this.

Anyway, I suggest you put this within life cycle methods. You can read more about them here:
https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#render

Please review the code, I've also added the removeEventListener when the component unmounts.

```
class Test extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('keypress', (e) => this.KeyPress(e))
  }
  
  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('keypress', (e) => this.KeyPress(e))
  }
  
  KeyPress(e){
    console.log(e.key)
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>hi there</h1>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Test />, document.querySelector("#app"))

ReactDOM.render(<Test />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question, I know that changing to non-arrow function fixes the bug, but I want to use the arrow notation to get around the binding of `this`. And hence, I would like to know why the arrow notation version does not work the same as the non-arrow function version.

Comment: I updated the code to using the arrow function around the keypress function call. Though, you would skip all this hassle by using functional components.

Comment: I will probably refactor into a functional component now for all the reasons you gave, but I was after the understanding not the workaround.

Comment: Just a heads up, you are calling `removeEventListener` here with a different function reference than the one that was added on mount.